# Solving a first order non-linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, error-function

I would like to know how to solve the following differential equation
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = 4y \biggl(\!-\frac{x}{2} - y \biggr) - \frac12
$$
but I'm not sure how to go about doing so given it is non-linear, inhomogeneous and has both explicit dependence on $x$ and $y$. I believe the answer is:
$$
y = -\frac{x}{2} + \frac{e^{x^{2}}}{C+2\sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{Erfi}(x)}
$$
where $C$ is a constant and $\operatorname{Erfi}$ is the [imaginary error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html). I know I could just check this solves the differential equation but I was wondering if there are any standard techniques or tricks I could use to derive this without knowing it, a priori. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Look at Ricatti's equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Comment: Awesome, thanks!